# Wifi Clients can't print to a network printer

Tags: wireless-networking, printing, printer

So I have a few users that I support that can't print to our network printer via wifi(Hp Officejet pro 8600 plus.) They are currently using windows 10 and I've tried the following;
I can ping it but can't get to the web interface,I reset everything, I checked the I.P. address of the printer, I've checked if the workstation had the right port selected,The firewall isn't blocking it, windows defender/firewall isn't blocking it, the network is considered a private network. There isn't any malware on it, and I turned off anti-virus and reinstalled it to no avail. I checked Net Bios over Tcp/IP. Everyone via LAN can print so I'm not sure what else it could be.

Comment: Figured it out, The physical firewall didn't have a policy set up for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the physical firewall was blocking the traffic via wifi for some reason. I say some reason because it worked with no issue up until last friday.

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following steps to add the network printer manually (we need to uninstall the network printer if we have already installed it).
Step 1: Find the hostname or IP address of the network printer.
[image]

Step 2: Click "next", type the printer hostname or IP address.
[image]

Step 3: Click "next", install the network printer, select a printer driver according to the model of our network printer.
Step 4: Click "next", type the name of our printer.
Step 5: Click "next", display the printer is installing.
Step 6: Click "next", share the printer according to our requirement.
Step 7: Click "next", check if we can print.

**Prompt:** sometimes the printer driver we selected does not work, we can change the printer driver in the same vendor(maybe the last one printer driver in the same vendor works).

If the printer still cannot work, based on your description, we need to config the physical firewall, maybe the printer port is blocked by the policies in physical firework.